# status-format settings for configuring multi-line status line in tmux

Tags: tmux

Amongst the changes listed under 'CHANGES FROM 2.8 to 2.9' in the tmux changelog  is that the status line can be multiple lines in height, and that the 'new status-format array option configures the format of each line'.

The tmux man page similarly indicates that the 'each line of the status line is configured with the status-format option'.

While there are lots of useful settings there I can't see how to individuate a line in a multi-line status line to apply specific settings to.

Apologies if I have missed or misunderstood the available information.

Answer (score 3):

Set status to 2 (or more) then set status-format[1]  (or higher) to your format for that status line.